# FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in Angular ng s command

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

While running `ng s` command of angular getting this error.

node version: **v20.10.0**
angular cli : **v17.0.6**
npm : **10.2.3**
os : **win32 x64**

[image]

Tried all the options which are available on internet still getting the same error while running the project.

Tried options like

1. SET NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8048
2. ng update @angular/cli —-next

Please help me out from this error.

Comment: *"Tried all the options"* then please include what you've tried and why it didn't work. Also include your code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because right now we have no clue what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Hiten `node --max_old_space_size=16000 ./node_modules/.bin/ng serve` try this!

Comment: @NarenMurali tried it but still getting the same error.